# How to replace a text in yml file with sed making sure that the indentation is preserved

Tags: awk, sed, yaml, indentation

I have a YAML file with the following content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: castlereport-cfg
  namespace: qa
data:
  application.properties: |
    BODY
```

I need to replace the BODY with the application.properties file content. I've used sed to do that like this:

```
sed -i -e '/BODY/r target/classes/application-dev.properties' -e 's///' -e '/^ *\$/d'  target/classes/$kubeConfigFile
```

It does what I need but loses the indentation and I what I get is this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: castlereport-cfg
  namespace: qa
data:
  application.properties: |

server.port=8080
server.context-path=/

spring.main.banner-mode=off
logbook.format.style=http
```

What should I do to keep the indentation?

And one more thing that `-e '/^ *\$/d'` part in the sed command is there to remove blank lines, but it doesn't seem to work either.

The Expected output is the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: castlereport-cfg
  namespace: qa
data:
  application.properties: |
    server.port=8080
    server.context-path=/
    spring.main.banner-mode=off
    logbook.format.style=http
```

UPDATE:
I have a Jenkins pipeline script where I am able to achieve what I want with the following three lines:

```
   sh ( script : "sed -i -e 's/^[ \t\$]*/   /' -e \"/^ *\$/d\"  ./target/classes/"+configFile, returnStdout: true).trim() //remove trailing spaces and blank lines
   sh ( script : "sed -i -e \"/BODY/r ./target/classes/"+configFile+"\" -e \"s///\" ./target/classes/" + configMapKubernetes, returnStdout: true).trim() // insert content of application-dev.properties to YAML file using BODY
   sh ( script : "sed -i -e \"/^ *\$/d\"  ./target/classes/" + configMapKubernetes, returnStdout: true).trim() //remove  blank lines
```

The pipeline script is in groovy so the whole command is inside double-quotes.

Comment: `\$` means a literal `$` char. Can't comment on the rest. Please add a block that shows your expected output (exactly ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for doing simple s/old/new on individual strings **that is all**. This awk script is probably what you want:

```
$cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    rec[++numLines] = $0
    next
}
s = index($0,"BODY") {
    indent = sprintf("%*s",s-1,"")
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
        print indent rec[lineNr]
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

For example, given these input files:

```
$ cat foo.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: castlereport-cfg
  namespace: qa
data:
  application.properties: |
    BODY

$ cat props
here is some text
    split across
  a few lines
```

we can do this which uses the BODY indentation from the yaml file but also retains any additional indentation from the props file:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk props foo.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: castlereport-cfg
  namespace: qa
data:
  application.properties: |
    here is some text
        split across
      a few lines
```

If you wanted instead to ignore the indentation from the `props` file and line all the props text up where BODY began that's a simple tweak:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
    rec[++numLines] = $0
    next
}
s = index($0,"BODY") {
    indent = sprintf("%*s",s-1,"")
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
        print indent rec[lineNr]
    }
    next
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk props foo.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: castlereport-cfg
  namespace: qa
data:
  application.properties: |
    here is some text
    split across
    a few lines
```

Comment: My answer does what you asked for so I don't see a need to re-read your question. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(\s*)BODY/sed "\/\\S\/!d;s#^#\1#" propertyFile/e' file
```

This solution replaces the line containing `BODY` by another sed invocation which appends the whitespace before the word `BODY` to each line from the property file. Empty lines are also removed from property file. If empty lines are also to be removed from the original file, use:

```
sed -E '/\S/!d;s/^(\s*)BODY/sed "\/\\S\/!d;s#^#\1#" propertyFile/e' file
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work. It doesn't replace the `BODY`. The output remains the same as the initial state.

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev perhaps you need to pass sed the `-i` option to update the original source file?

Comment: This confused me for a bit before I realized that the key to understanding it is the `e` command (the last character in the string argument to the top level sed invocation). My local man page doesn't describe it, but apparently it runs whatever is in the second pattern space with `sh -c` and uses its output to populate matches from the first pattern space; in this case, a subsequent sed invocation is executed and provided the back reference `\1`, which matched leading whitespace, in order to maintain the indent of the original line.